# Secure method to store PHP object in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, security, object, owasp

How do I securely save PHP objects in a MySQL Database?

If you use the serialize and unserialize functions, you may end up with Object Injections (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection).

Is there a predefined standard on how to handle this?

Note that SQL injection =/= object injection! So PDO is a different story here!

Comment: there's nothing wrong about using unserialize; what is unsafe is to pass user input directly to unserialize. Anyway IMHO is better to use something more portable, as JSON, to store objects in a database.

Comment: What @isalgueiro says; if your server is serializing and unserializing the object, there is no problem, snice there is no user-input involved.

Answer (score 1):

you can save the object in MySQL as JSON by using json_encode

```
json_encode($object);
```

Then you can store it in MySQL and use json_decode to start us it as object

```
$object = json_decode($result->object);
```

also, the best way to save the JSON into your MySQL database to store it as text

Comment: is JsonSerializable not better?

Comment: There is no need to use. just json_encode and save your object in the database

Answer (score 1):

Just save it as text. You could use serialize or json_encode.

However i would suggest json_encode due to the fact that you could return it in ajax posts directly if you have a flexible UI or use some nice frontend frameworks.

Just my 2 cents.